# What is the max thread count for boost asio io_context?

Tags: c++, boost-asio, asio

```
 int threads = 1;
// Run the I/O service on the requested number of threads
std::vector<std::thread> v;
v.reserve(threads - 1);
for (auto i = threads - 1; i > 0; --i)
    v.emplace_back(
        [&ioc]
        {
            ioc.run();
        });
ioc.run();
```

How can I give threads value dynamically?

Example for windows socket;

```
while (true)
    {
        SOCKET new_socket_id = m_socket_ptr->accept();
    }
```

I should be able to accept all incoming requests at the same time
Even if the process takes a long time in the request handler, I should not keep other requests waiting.

Comment: Depends on the thread workload.  CPU intensive: having more threads then the CPU physically has is counter productive.  IO bound: use a thread queue that can add more threads if threads managed by the thread queue block waiting for IO.  Either way you are going to need to measure it with a realistic load simulator.

Comment: Are you looking for [thread hardware concurrency](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/hardware_concurrency)?

Comment: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/master/libs/beast/example/advanced/server/advanced_server.cpp , The example in the link works for one thread, which means that it answers one request, if that link takes a long time to respond, it makes other requests wait. I can increase the number of threads to prevent this, but it is not a dynamic solution. What is the best practice for this on real systems?